# Manipulação de arquivos em C

Tags: c

Estou tentando criar um arquivo, com números aleatórios e em seguida gerar um novo arquivo com os números em ordem crescente. Só que na hora de gerar esse novo arquivo, fica cheio de números estranhos e ele só deixa o arquivo em ordem quando vou no código e altero o arquivo = fopen(nome, "w"); para arquivo = fopen(nome, "r"); ai eu compilo novamente e ele deixa em ordem.

Como resolver isso sem que precise alterar o código toda hora?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

void crecente(int *vet);
//--- Função principal---
int main(void)
{
    int vet[100]; 

    crecente(&vet[0]);
    printf("--- Vetor foi organizado com sucesso ---\n\n");

    return 0 ;
}

void crecente(int *vet)
{
    int i,j, acumulador;

    FILE *arquivo;
    FILE *novo;
    char nome[10];
    int quantidade, cont;

    printf("Digite o nome do arquivo:");
      scanf("%s", nome);
    printf("Digite a quantidade de numeros:");
    scanf("%d", &quantidade);

    arquivo = fopen(nome, "w");
  
  if (arquivo==NULL) {
        printf("Falha ao criar o arquivo.");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        for (cont=1;cont<=quantidade;cont++) 
            fprintf(arquivo, "%d\n", rand()%100);
    }

    /*--- Lendo e coletando as informações do primeiro arquivo --- */
    for(i = 0; i < 100 ; i++)
    {
        fscanf(arquivo, "%d\n", &vet[i]);
    }

    /*--- Criando o segundo arquivo para ordenar --- */
    novo = fopen("ordemcrescente.txt", "w+");
    /*--- Ordenando as informações que estavam dentro do arquivo ---*/
    for(i = 0; i<100; i++)
    {
        for(j = i+1 ; j<100; j++)
        {
            if(vet[i]>vet[j])
            {
                acumulador = vet[i];
                vet[i] = vet[j];
                vet[j] = acumulador;
            }
        }
    }
    /*--- Imprimindo dentro do novo arquivo ---*/
    for(j = 0 ; j<100 ; j++)
    {
        fprintf(novo, "%d\n", vet[j]);
    }
    /*--- Fechando os arquivos ---*/
    fclose(arquivo);
    fclose(novo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Só que na hora de gerar esse novo arquivo, fica cheio de números estranhos e ele só deixa o arquivo em ordem quando vou no código e altero o arquivo = fopen(nome, "w"); para arquivo = fopen(nome, "r"); ai eu compilo novamente e ele deixa em ordem.
>
> Como resolver isso sem que precise alterar o código toda hora?

O programa tem alguns erros comuns. Entenda que seu programa tem umas fases:

- cria um arquivo
- abre um arquivo e carrega seu conteúdo para um vetor
- classifica um vetor na memória
- cria um arquivo com o conteúdo desse vetor

Crie seu código em torno dessas fases, e teste separado. É muito mais simples e vai levar muito menos tempo para terminar.

**Escreva:**

- um programa que cria o arquivo com esses números. E teste.
- um programa que classifica um vetor e cria um arquivo com o conteúdo. Use um vetor numerado ao contrário do critério de classificação. É o rápido.
- um programa que cria um arquivo a partir do conteúdo de um vetor.

Ao fazer esses simples programas vai ver que não testou quantos elementos leu do arquivo inicial para o vetor, então sempre vai gerar 100 linhas na saída, o tamanho do vetor, mesmo que tenha lido só 4 na entrada

E claro que o contrário também é verdade: não estou se tem mais de 100 linhas na entrada e se tiver seu programa vai cancelar

#### sobre seu programa

- entenda que para criar o arquivo usa um modo, o popular `"w"` já que vai gravar nele, mas para ler de volta e colocar no vetor precisa abrir para leitura, o popular `"r"`. E você recompilou o programa para ler o arquivo de outro modo, não sei se entendi o que fez. Mas o simples é apenas reabrir o arquivo com o modo certo
- claro que ler de volta os dados é supérfluo. Podia ter carregado o vetor ao mesmo tempo em que criava o arquivo de saída. Desde que tenha o arquivo de entrada e o arquivo de saída na pasta poderá conferir a classificação. Ninguém vai saber se abriu o arquivo para ler os dados que o MESMO programa acabou de gravar

```
void crecente(int *vet);
//--- Função principal---
int main(void)
```

- sugiro evitar esse tipo de comentário. Se sabe que uma função chamada `main` em um programa em C é a *"principal"*.
- evite acentos em comentários. Pouco acrescentam e podem não sair direito na tela
- "crescente" é a grafia comum.
- evite programas interativos. São chatos de usar. Claro, a menos que esteja seguindo um enunciado. Use parâmetros. Seu programa usa 3: os nomes dos arquivos e a quantidade de elementos. Use a linha de comando.
- evite funções que retornam `void`. Em geral é um desperdício, muitas vezes um erro.
- se não precisa mesmo classificar no programa use `qsort()` que a linguagem oferece
- se vai usar sort em um arquivo que está lendo linha a linha use *insertion sort*, e classifique enquanto lê.

```
void crescente(int *vet)
```

E como vai saber o tamanho do vetor?

```
int main(void)
{
    int vet[100];
    crecente(&vet[0]);
    printf("--- Vetor foi organizado com sucesso ---\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

- Se retornasse algo da função saberia se de fato organizou com sucesso.
- `&vet[0]` é a mesma coisa que `vet`. E não passou o tamanho do vetor então é bem provável que vá ler valores estranhos, a menos que tenha lido exatamente 100. E se tinha 101 na entrada seu programa já teria cancelado.
- separe as funções. `crecente()` não deveria ler arquivos ou gravar. Só passou todo o código de `main()` para `crecente()`.

#### um exemplo mais simples em C

Vou editar seu programa e deixar um exemplo mais simples a seguir. Pode ser útil pra você comparar. A razão dos erros acho que já expliquei acima.

#### o plano

```
    pgm X entrada saida
```

Isso é o simples. O programa não roda sem isso então é muito chato usar o programa sabendo que ele vai perguntar isso, e ficar teclando ENTER toda hora. o programa, ENTER, o total de números, ENTER, o arquivo de entrada, ENTER, o arquivo de saída, ENTER...

E se faltar algo não tem como seguir.

Como eu disse antes, é melhor usar programas pequenos e depois juntar.

Veja esse:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 4)
    {
        printf("\
\n\
    Use: programa tamanho original saida\n\
\n\
        onde 'tamanho' = total de elementos e\n\
        'original' e 'saida' sao os nomes dos arquivos\n\
\n\
    ex: tst 300 entrada.txt saida.txt\n\n"
        );
        return -1;
    };
    int quantidade = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf(
      "    %d valores aleatorios serao gerados e gravados em \"%s\" e\
 depois ordenados e gravados em  \"%s\"",
        quantidade, argv[2], argv[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Que mostra

```
SO>./f2

    Use: programa tamanho original saida

        onde 'tamanho' = total de elementos e
        'original' e 'saida' sao os nomes dos arquivos

    ex: tst 300 entrada.txt saida.txt

SO>./f2 400 a.txt saida.txt
    400 valores aleatorios serao gerados e gravados em "a.txt" e depois ordenados e gravados em  "saida.txt"
SO>
```

É mais simples.

#### usando funções objetivas e copiar e colar

É mais simples escrever uma coisa por vez e usar apenas variáveis locais e parâmetros

##### gerando o arquivo com os números iniciais

```
    int gera_dados(int quant, char* arquivo)
    {
    FILE* sai = fopen(arquivo, "w");
    if (sai == NULL) return -1;

    for (int cont = 1; cont <= quant; cont++)
        fprintf(sai, "%d\n", rand() % 100);
    fclose(sai);
    return 0;
}
```

Recebe a quantidade e o nome do arquivo. Então pode testar com várias quantidades e vários arquivos sem ter que olhar o resto do programa.

##### gravando o vetor ordenado

```
int grava_vetor(int vet[], int quantidade, char* arquivo)
{
    FILE* sai = fopen(arquivo, "w");
    if (sai == NULL) return -1;
    for (int cont = 0; cont < quantidade; cont++)
        fprintf(sai, "%d\n", vet[cont]);
    fclose(sai);
    return 0;
}
```

Assim não tem que testar nada fora disso, desde que ao chamar a função passe uma quantidade válida.

##### o sort

```
int         compare( const void* um, const void* outro )
{
    int* a = (int*)um;
    int* b = (int*)outro;
    if (*a < *b) return -1;
    if (*a > *b) return +1;
    return 0;
}
```

Está classificando `int` então essa função acima compara dois `int` e retorna 1 se estão fora de ordem. E aí pode usar

```
int ordena_vetor(int quantidade, int vet[])
{
    qsort( (void*)vet, quantidade, sizeof(vet[0]), compare);
    return 0;
}
```

E o programa classifica o vetor. Faz parte de stdlib afinal. MAs se escrever assim pode classificar omo quiser, sem mexer no resto do programa.

Acho que deu pra entender o que tento mostrar. Cansei de escrever ;)

##### um programa de teste completo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int  compare(const void*, const void*); // para o sort, padrao
int  gera_dados(int quant, char* arquivo);
int  grava_vetor(int vet[], int quantidade, char* arquivo);
int  le_vetor(char* arquivo, int vet[], int limite);
int  ordena_vetor(int quantidade, int vet[]);
void uso();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int vet[100];
    int limite = sizeof(vet) / sizeof(int);

    if (argc < 4) uso();  // mostra mensagem e cancela

    // ok: mostra os parametros ANTES de seguir
    int quantidade = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf(
        "\
    %d valores aleatorios serao gerados e gravados em \"%s\" e\
 depois ordenados e gravados em  \"%s\"\n\n",
        quantidade, argv[2], argv[3]);

    // gera o vetor e grava o arquivo
    int res = gera_dados(quantidade, argv[2]);
    if (res != 0)
    {
        printf("erro ao gerar \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("    %d elementos gravados em \"%s\"\n", quantidade,
           argv[2]);

    // le o arquivo e preenche o vetor ate o limite dos dados
    // redefine a quantidade
    quantidade = le_vetor(argv[2], vet, limite);
    if (res != 0)
    {
        printf("erro ao gerar \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("    Vetor carregado com %d elementos a partir de \"%s\"\n",
           quantidade, argv[2]);

    // classifica o vetor
    res = ordena_vetor(quantidade, vet);
    printf("    %d elementos ordenados\n", quantidade);

    // grava na saida
    res = grava_vetor(vet, quantidade, argv[3]);
    if (res != 0)
    {
        printf("erro ao gerar \"%s\"\n", argv[3]);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("    \"%s\" gravado com %d elementos\n", argv[3],
           quantidade);
    return 0;
}

int         compare( const void* um, const void* outro )
{
    int* a = (int*)um;
    int* b = (int*)outro;
    if (*a < *b) return -1;
    if (*a > *b) return +1;
    return 0;
}

    int gera_dados(int quant, char* arquivo)
    {
    FILE* sai = fopen(arquivo, "w");
    if (sai == NULL) return -1;

    for (int cont = 1; cont <= quant; cont++)
        fprintf(sai, "%d\n", rand() % 100);
    fclose(sai);
    return 0;
}

int grava_vetor(int vet[], int quantidade, char* arquivo)
{
    FILE* sai = fopen(arquivo, "w");
    if (sai == NULL) return -1;
    for (int cont = 0; cont < quantidade; cont++)
        fprintf(sai, "%d\n", vet[cont]);
    fclose(sai);
    return 0;
}

int le_vetor(char* arquivo, int vet[], int limite)
{
    FILE* ent = fopen(arquivo, "r");
    if (ent == NULL) return -1;
    int quant = 0;
    for ( quant = 0; quant < limite; quant++)
    {   // le o que da, ate o limite
        int res = fscanf(ent, "%d", vet + quant); 
        if (res != 1) return quant; // acabou
    }
    fclose(ent);
    return quant;
}

int ordena_vetor(int quantidade, int vet[])
{
    qsort( (void*)vet, quantidade, sizeof(vet[0]), compare);
    return 0;
}

void uso()
{
    printf(
        "\
\n\
    Use: programa tamanho original saida\n\
\n\
        onde 'tamanho' = total de elementos e\n\
        'original' e 'saida' sao os nomes dos arquivos\n\
\n\
    ex: tst 300 entrada.txt saida.txt\n\n");
    exit(-1);
};
```

##### um teste com 4 valores

```
SO>./f4 4 a.txt b.txt
    4 valores aleatorios serao gerados e gravados em "a.txt" e depois ordenados e gravados em  "b.txt"

    4 elementos gravados em "a.txt"
    Vetor carregado com 4 elementos a partir de "a.txt"
    4 elementos ordenados
    "b.txt" gravado com 4 elementos
SO>type a.txt
41
67
34
0
SO> type b.txt
0
34
41
67
SO>
```

Comment: Muuuuito obrigado pela explicação! Me ajudou muito. Estava um pouco perdido mas agora estou conseguindo fazer a continuação do código. Realmente, testar por partes faz melhorar o entendimento e achar o erro. Obrigado.

Comment: Marque tal resposta como útil ou como solução de seu problema. Assim ajuda outros com questão semelhante a chegarem até aqui